# Is there a way to force MacOSX to Sort Folders on Top of Files (Windows Style)?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

Is there a way to force MacOSX to Sort Folders on Top of Files (Windows Style)? The default setting is always messy and annoying.

Answer (score 1):

cd /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/ (or whatever language you're running)

```
sudo plutil -convert xml1 InfoPlist.strings
sudo nano InfoPlist.strings (edit folder here)
sudo plutil -convert binary1 InfoPlist.strings
```

white using nano locate Folder and put an empty space there to get  Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Finder preferences -> Advanced -> check "Keep folders on top when sorting by name"

[image: Finder prefrences]

[image: Advanced tab]